# My quote generator works on mobile but not on desktop

Tags: javascript, html, css

Like the title says. I have done the FCC challenge quote generator. Was working fine on all platforms until this morning and now it's only working on mobile. No clue as to what is causing this. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/Skitto/pen/dOrXNy
HTML

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/225c9ed469.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="background outerswag">

 <div class="box">

  <div class="text-center">

      <h2 id="quote"> Welcome to the quote generator, enjoy your stay.</h2>
      <h4 id="author"></h4>


  </div>

  <div class = "text-center">
    <button id = "quoteGETJSON" class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg outline glyphicon glyphicon-repeat" onclick="this.blur();"></button>
    <button id = "tweet" class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg outline fa fa-twitter" onclick="this.blur();"></button>
    <h5>created by Skitto</h5>
    </div>


  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
    html{
  background:url("https://source.unsplash.com/category/nature/1920x1080")no-repeat center center fixed;

-webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.box{
    padding:10%;
    color:white;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: -100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    width: 100%;

}
.text{
  max-width:50%;
} 
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
}

.btn-lg {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.btn-primary {
  color: white;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: white;
}

.btn-primary:hover,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: grey;
  border-color: grey;
}

/***********************
  OUTLINE BUTTONS
************************/

.btn.outline {
    background: none;
    padding: 12px 22px;
}
.btn-primary.outline {
    border: 2px solid white;
    color: white;
}
.btn-primary.outline:hover, .btn-primary.outline:focus, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    color: black;
    border-color: black;
}

/***********************
  CUSTON BTN VALUES
************************/

.btn {
    padding: 14px 24px;
    border: 0 none;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.btn:focus{
    outline: 0 none;
}
```

Javascript

```
var authorglobal="";
var quoteglobal="";
$('#quoteGETJSON').click(function() {
  $.getJSON("http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&lang=en&format=jsonp&jsonp=?")
    .done(update)
    .fail(handleErr);
});


function update(quote) {
  $('#quote').html(JSON.stringify(quote.quoteText));
  quoteglobal=JSON.stringify(quote.quoteText);
  if(quote.quoteAuthor==""){
    $('#author').html('-Unknown');
    authorglobal="-Uknown";
  }else{
    var string="-";
       string+= JSON.stringify(quote.quoteAuthor);
      var returnable=string.replace(/"/g,"");
      authorglobal=returnable;
  $('#author').html(returnable);
  }
 //$('html').css('background', 'url(hre)');
}

function handleErr(jqxhr, textStatus, err) {
  console.log("Request Failed: " + textStatus + ", " + err);
}

$('#tweet').click(function(){
  var url="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=quotes&text="+quoteglobal+authorglobal;

  window.open(url) ;
});
```

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for any error reports or done any debugging?

Comment: there is 1 closing div tag (`</div>`) to much at the end of your html!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it is not working is that Your codepen url is https but You request http resource. There is [mixed content error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content)

If You open codepen via http it will work: http://codepen.io/Skitto/pen/dOrXNy

You should use same protocol for all resources. You can also specify url like: "//google.com" which will set same protocol as current page uses. For Your case it would be:

```
$.getJSON("//api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&lang=en&format=jsonp&jsonp=?")
```

But setting it in Your codepen and running it via https will not work, cause there is certificate error api.forismatic.com

Happy hacking!

Comment: So it's just a matter of these two not being compatible while in the https mode. Thank you for your answer, it makes way more sense now!

Comment: Yes it is. If it helped You I would be grateful for upvoting answer and marking it as solution ;) Be aware that if You use resources from https then they have to has proper ssl certificate to load.